# Serenity BDD report doesn't generate visual parts in Window 10 after 3.7.0 version

Tags: windows, gradle, report, upgrade, serenity

I have a project for testing API that use Java, Gradle and Serenity to tests **APIs**, that works perfectly in different OS.

When I try to upgrade the Serenity libraries from 3.7.0 to **3.9.0 or any upper** (ex: 3.9.0 or 4.0.15 or whichever in between), the tests are properly executed in any OS, but curiusly just in Windows 10 it **doesn't** generate the visual parts of the report. No `css`, nor `ico`, nor `png`, nor bootstrap foulder, etc. This results in a basic `html` report.

In Unix or Mac the report is generated properly whichever version, we have tried and it works. Just not in Windows OS.

Relevant configuration: Java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS

- **build.gradle:**

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
          mavenLocal()
          mavenCentral()
          maven {
              url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
          }
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:3.9.0"
          classpath "com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.22.0"
          classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:4.4.1.3373"
      }
  }

  plugins {
      id "com.diffplug.spotless" version "6.22.0"
  }

  repositories {
      jcenter()
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      maven {
          url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
      }
  }

  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: "net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin"
  apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'


  group 'Zinio API Automation Framework'

  dependencies {
      // EMAIL handler
      implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'

      // JSON files handlers
      implementation 'org.json:json:20231013'
      implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.8.0'
      implementation 'com.networknt:json-schema-validator:1.0.87'

      // LOGGER
      implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9'
      implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.9'

      // ZIP handler
      implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5'

      // BDD SUITE: SERENITY + CUCUMBER + REST-ASSURED
      implementation 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:3.9.0'
      implementation 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:3.9.0'
      testImplementation 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:3.9.0'
      implementation 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:3.9.0'
  }

  wrapper {
      gradleVersion = '8.4'
  }

  gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true

  test {
      systemProperties System.getProperties()
      testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
      test.reports.html.required.set(false)
      test.reports.junitXml.required.set(false)
      include "testRunner/TestRunner.class"
  }

  javadoc {
      source = sourceSets.test.allJava
      classpath = sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
      destinationDir = file("documentation/javadoc")
  }

  gradle.projectsEvaluated {
      tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
          options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
      }
  }
  ```
- **gradle-wrapper.properties:**

  ```
  distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  distributionPath=wrapper/dists
  distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
  zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
  ```
- **serenity.properties:**

  ```
  max.retries=3
  junit.retry.tests=true
  ```
- **TestRunner.java:**

  ```
  @RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
  @CucumberOptions(
          features = "src/test/java/service/services",
          plugin = {
                  "pretty",
                  "html:target/cucumber_html.html",
                  "json:target/cucumber_json.json",
                  "junit:target/junit.xml"
          },
          glue = "service")
  ```

I would like to be able to update the Serenity libraries and generate and see the Serenity BDD report with all the visual parts in Windows 10.